# Docker login to Gitea registry fails even though curl succeeds

Tags: docker, gitea

I'm using Gitea (on Kubernetes, behind an Ingress) as a Docker image registry. On my network I have `gitea.avril` aliased to the IP where it's running. I recently found that my Kubernetes cluster was failing to pull images:

```
Failed to pull image "gitea.avril/scubbo/<image_name>:<tag>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "gitea.avril/scubbo/<image_name>:<tag>": failed to resolve reference "gitea.avril/scubbo/<image_name>:<tag>": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 530
```

While trying to debug this, I found that I am unable to login to the registry, even though `curl`ing with the same credentials succeeds:

```
$ curl -k -u "scubbo:$(cat /tmp/gitea-password)" https://gitea.avril/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[...populated list...]}
# Tell docker login to treat `gitea.avril` as insecure, since certificate is provided by Kubernetes
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
        "insecure-registries": ["gitea.avril"]
}
$ docker login -u scubbo -p $(cat /tmp/gitea-password) https://gitea.avril
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://gitea.avril/v2/": received unexpected HTTP status: 530
```

The first request shows up as a `200 OK` in the Gitea logs, the second as a `401 Unauthorized`.

I get a similar error when I `kubectl exec` onto the Gitea container itself, install Docker, and try to `docker login localhost:3000` - after an error indicating that `server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`, it falls back to the http protocol and similarly reports a 530.

I've tried restart Gitea with `GITEA__log__LEVEL=Debug`, but that didn't result in any extra logging. I've also tried creating a fresh user (in case I have some weirdness cached somewhere) and using that - same behaviour.

EDIT: after increasing log level to `Trace`, I noticed that successful attempts to `curl` result in the following lines:

```
...rvices/auth/basic.go:67:Verify() [T] [638d16c4] Basic Authorization: Attempting login for: scubbo
...rvices/auth/basic.go:112:Verify() [T] [638d16c4] Basic Authorization: Attempting SignIn for scubbo
...rvices/auth/basic.go:125:Verify() [T] [638d16c4] Basic Authorization: Logged in user 1:scubbo
```

whereas attempts to `docker login` result in:

```
...es/container/auth.go:27:Verify() [T] [638d16d4] ParseAuthorizationToken: no token
```

This is the case even when doing `docker login localhost:3000` from the Gitea container itself (that is - this is not due to some authentication getting dropped by the Kubernetes Ingress).

I'm not sure what could be causing this - I'll start up a fresh Gitea registry to compare.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: in [this Github issue](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/22033), the Gitea team pointed out that standard docker authentication includes creating a `Bearer` token which references the `ROOT_URL`, explaining this issue.**

Text below preserved for posterity:

---

...Huh. I have a fix, and I *think* it indicates some incorrect (or, at least, unexpected) behaviour; but in fairness it only comes about because [I'm doing some pretty unexpected things as well](https://xkcd.com/1172/)...

**TL;DR attempting to `docker login` to Gitea from an alternative domain name can result in an error if the primary domain name is unavailable; apparently because, while doing so, Gitea itself makes a call to `ROOT_URL` rather than `localhost`**

### Background

Gitea has a configuration variable called `ROOT_URL`. This is, among other things, used to generate the copiable "HTTPS" links from repo pages. This is presumed to be the "main" URL on which users will access Gitea.

I use [Cloudflared Tunnels](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps) to make some of my Kubernetes services (including Gitea) available externally (on `<foo>.scubbo.org` addresses) without opening ports to the outside world. Since Cloudflared tunnels [do not automatically update DNS records when a new service is added](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/issues/739), I have written a [small tool](https://gitea.scubbo.org/scubbo/cloudflaredtunneldns)[0] which can be run as an `initContainer` "before" restarting the Cloudflared tunnel, to refresh DNS[1].

### Cold-start problem

However, now there is a cold-start problem:

- (Unless I temporarily disable this `initContainer`) I can't start Cloudflared tunnels if Gitea is unavailable (because it's the source for the `initContainer`'s image)
- Gitea('s public address) will be unavailable until Cloudflared tunnels start up.

To get around this cold-start problem, in the Cloudflared `initContainers` definition, I reference the image by a Kubernetes Ingress name (which is DNS-aliased by my router) `gitea.avril` rather than by the public (Cloudflared tunnel) name `gitea.scubbo.org`. The cold-start startup sequence then becomes:

- Cloudflared tries to start up, fails to find a registry at `gitea.avril`, continues to attempt
- Gitea (Pod and Ingress) start up
- Cloudflared detects that `gitea.avril` is now responding, pulls the Cloudflared initContainer image, and successfully deploys
- `gitea.scubbo.org` is now available (via Cloudflared)

So far, so good. Except that testing now indicates[2] that, when trying to `docker login` (or `docker pull`, or presumably, many other `docker` commands) to a Gitea instance will result in a call to the `ROOT_URL` domain - which, if Cloudflared isn't up yet, will result in an error[3].

### So what?

My particular usage of this is clearly an edge case, and I could easily get around this in a number of ways (including moving my "*Cloudflared tunnel startup*" to a separately-initialized, only-privately-available registry). However, what this reduces to is that "*`docker` API calls to a Gitea instance will fail if the `ROOT_URL` for the instance is unavailable*", which seems like unexpected behaviour to me - if the API call can get through to the Gitea service in the first place, it should be able to succeed in calling itself?

However, I totally recognize that the complexity of fixing this (going through and replacing `$ROOT_URL` with `localhost:$PORT` throughout Gitea) might not be worth the value. I'll open an issue on the Gitea team, but I'd be perfectly content with a `WILLNOTFIX`.

### Footnotes

[0]: Note - depending on when you follow that link, you might see a red warning banner indicating "_Your ROOT_URL in app.ini is https://gitea.avril/ but you are visiting [https://gitea.scubbo.org/scubbo/cloudflaredtunneldns_"](https://gitea.scubbo.org/scubbo/cloudflaredtunneldns_%22). That's because of this very issue!

[1]: Note from the [linked issue](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/issues/739) that the Cloudflared team indicate that this is unexpected usage - "*We don't expect the origins to be dynamically added or removed services behind cloudflared*".

[2]: I *think* this is new behaviour, as I'm reasonably certain that I've done a successful "cold start" before. However, I wouldn't swear to it.

[3]: After I've , the error is instead `error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""` rather than the 530-related errors I got before. This is probably a quirk of Cloudflared's caching or DNS behaviour. I'm working on a minimal reproducing example that circumvents Cloudflared.